# Apache Lucene 5.3.0 release KEYS: missing key 3FCFDB3E

Tags: apache, lucene, key, sign, pgp

I am trying to install Apache Lucene 5.3.0 (from source). The mirror sites provide `lucene-5.3.0-src.tgz` and `lucene-5.3.0-src.tgz.asc` (the signature file), however the latter is using RSA key ID `3FCFDB3E` which is not contained in the `KEYS` file (which is also provided).

`` $ gpg --verify ./lucene-5.3.0-src.tgz.asc 
gpg: assuming signed data in `./lucene-5.3.0-src.tgz'
gpg: Signature made 2015-08-17T13:35:34 CEST using RSA key ID 3FCFDB3E
gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found ``

The issue seems to be affecting multiple sites. What should the fingerprint be? Why is the key not included in the `KEYS` file?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the [key of Paul Noble](http://pool.sks-keyservers.net/pks/lookup?op=vindex&search=0x3FCFDB3E&fingerprint=on) is what you're looking for, having fingerprint

```
CFCE 5FBB 920C 3C74 5CEE  E084 C38F F5EC 3FCF DB3E
```

The key is rather new (a bunch of weeks old).

You cannot be really sure whether he's permitted to release for Apache Lucene, nor that the key actually belongs to him.

A short [Google survey at least indicates several contributions to free software](https://www.google.com/?q=3fcfdb3e), and also the Linux kernel, but this should not be considered trustworthy without further analysis. There are also no incoming certifications that could be used to verify the key through the web of trust.

I'd recommend to get in touch with Apache, possibly on the Lucene mailing list, and query the developers how to verify the release based on what trust assumptions. And indicate there's something wrong which they should change (eg., include the key in the KEYS file).

Answer (score 0):

the policies around where KEYS files are "published" for the lucene project is kind of confusing, compounded by the use of id.apache.org -> people.apache.org and it's automatic generation of a KEYS file for each project committee based on their current keys.  some backstory here...

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-5143

The current policy is that each new Lucene/Solr release publishes a snapshot of all the current keys, so for 5.3.0 that would be here...

https://www.apache.org/dist/lucene/java/5.3.0/KEYS

...but the older "non version specific" keys files are still available - notably for verifying older versions of software in the archives that may predate the current policy.

You can always see the list of all "active" keys for a given apache project/user using http://people.apache.org/keys/

http://people.apache.org/keys/group/lucene.asc